# ndarray map_inplace with index

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

How do you `map_inplace` or `par_map_inplace` in an ndarray while using the index of the current element you're mapping over?

```rust
array.map_inplace(|val| {
    *val = (expression involving the index)
})
```

You can keep track of a global counter for the non-parallel version, but this won't work for the parallel version.

Comment: A global will not work, not even in the non parallel case because [*"Elements are visited in arbitrary order."*](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.map_inplace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non-parallel in-place mutation with index, you can use [`.indexed_iter_mut()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.indexed_iter_mut) like so:

```
array.indexed_iter_mut()
    .for_each(|(index, val)| {
        *val = (expression involving the index)
    });
```

For a parallel version, you would need to use rayon's [`.par_bridge()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelBridge.html#tymethod.par_bridge) since `IndexedIterMut` isn't inherently a parallel iterator (ndarray uses rayon internally for parallelization):

```
use rayon::iter::{ParallelBridge, ParallelIterator};

array.indexed_iter_mut()
    .par_bridge()
    .for_each(|(index, val)| {
        *val = (expression involving the index)
    });
```